# Selecting the column which is not available

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a PHP script and wanted to get the result with the same select query.

Let me explain it for some tables one column is not present so I have created a query to search if the column is present or not.

```
id={1,2,3,4,5};
$val=select (case when exists (select * from information_schema.columns where table_name='X{id}' and TABLE_SCHEMA='employee' and column_name='EmpID' ) then 1 else 0  end)

//checking if the column EmpID is present or not

if($val==0)
select emp_name,age,address,'EmpID' from employee.X{id};
elseif($val==1)
select emp_name,age,address,EmpID from employee.X{id};
```

Currently if $val=1, then the output is coming properly.

If $val=0, I wanted to display EmpID as blank(I know that field is not present for that table)

I am passing these values to run another ETL process, so I wanted the data to be passed in same format all the time. That's the reason I wanted the EmpID to be blank

Please help me with this.

Comment: Is that supposed to be PHP?

Comment: It's a PHP script which I am trying to do. But selecting is not working as I expected

Comment: There is a 0% chance of the "output coming properly" for any of this.

Comment: Sorry, but thats not PHP, so the question becomes a bit difficult to answer as it stops making any sense

Comment: Please google, how to run mysql using php pdo.  Probably the best place for you to start.

Comment: @sweety do the columns not exist or is the corresponding row empty? column must exist for the select statement to work...